# How to track user actions on files of a directory?

Tags: perforce

We use Perforce for version control on Windows 7, but lately I have been encountering certain problems with it. Permissions to some files and directories seem to change without any reason. I want to find what action is causing change in these permissions. I would like to track all actions that take place on files within a particular directory so that if such problems are encountered again, I can look-up some kind of log and find what caused it. Is there someway this can be done?

Comment: It's not clear from this question which permissions are changing -- Perforce's protection table?  The filetypes of the depot files (which determine the permission bits when a file is freshly synced)?  Are the workspace permission bits changing independently of a sync operation?    These would all have different root causes; the first two can be tracked since they're happening in Perforce, but if someone's fiddling with a workspace outside of Perforce control I'd suggest locking down the machine so people can't fiddle with it (it is not recommended to share workspaces in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Once in if you sink files from perforce,it changes the file permission of of those files to read-only to ensure those files are not modified.(Thats how the application is meant to work)

If your intention is to modify and submit it to perforce then you can checkout the files which you want to modify or update (It removes readonly from those checked-out files)

[image]

So, if you need to modify those files with an intention of not submitting them then,you got to manually remove readonly the file permission.

Hope this helps :)